# How to add control to the module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've seen a few examples but they are outdated.
I'm using standard template for module creation with View, Edit, Setting.

I'm adding a new control `TestPage : MyModuleBase`
in mymodule.dnn

```
<moduleControl>
<controlKey>TestPage</controlKey>
<controlSrc>DesktopModules/mymodule/TestPage.ascx</controlSrc>
<supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
<controlTitle>TestPage.ascx</controlTitle>
<controlType>Edit</controlType>
<iconFile />
<helpUrl />
<viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
</moduleControl>
```

then on View on button click:

```
this.Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(this.TabId, "TestPage"));
```

and it redirects to /mymodule/ctl/TestPage/portalid/0 and it is empty.
What is wrong in my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use EditURL instead of NavigateURL in order to specify you want to load a specific control for the module that the moduleID is specified in the URL.